# Creating publishing pages using SharePoint Server Object Model in SP 2010

Tags: ssom

I am trying to create new pages in my publishing site(need to use a custom page layout) using SharePoint Server Object Model. I couldn't find much help on this topic from internet.

Happy to have some references from you.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing is the assembly that we need to use to get pages created and published.  A sample is provided below:

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://moss"))
    {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
    PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(site);
    SPContentType ctype = pSite.ContentTypes["Welcome Page"];
    PageLayoutCollection pageLayouts = pSite.GetPageLayouts(ctype, true);
    PageLayout pageLayout = pageLayouts["/_catalogs/masterpage/welcomesplash.aspx"];
    PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
    PublishingPageCollection pPages = pWeb.GetPublishingPages();
    PublishingPage pPage = pPages.Add("Programmatic_Test.aspx", pageLayout);
    SPListItem newpage = pPage.ListItem;
    newpage["Title"] = "Page added programmatically";
    newpage.Update();

    newpage.File.CheckIn("all looks good");
    newpage.File.Publish("all looks good");
    }
    }
```

[reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2008/06/21/create-and-publish-web-pages-in-publishing-sharepoint-sites-programmatically.aspx?Redirected=true)